# Transfer data from one page to another through link of the other file in asp.net

Tags: c#

I am trying to send the data of one page to another. I am using following code but it is not working.

```
<a id="A1" href='Readmore.aspx?oid= <%# Eval("title").ToString() %>' >Read More.</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
<a id="A1" href='<%# Eval("title","Readmore.aspx?oid={0}") %>' >Read More.</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing like this,

```
 <a id="A1" href='<%# "Readmore.aspx?oid="+Eval("title")%>' >Read More.</a>
```